# « je le dois plûtot à ma chance qu'à une vertu incapable de résister à rien »

Tags: grammaire, traduction, négation

I'm a bit confused by a phrase in Marguerite Yourcenar's *Mémoires d'Hadrien*:

> Et cependant, si j'ai à peu près renoncé à ces formes par trop machinales du plaisir, ou ne m'y suis pas enfoncé trop avant, je le dois plutôt à ma chance qu'à **une vertu incapable de résister à rien**.

The English translation renders this as

> And nevertheless, if I have virtually given up these too mechanical forms of pleasure, or have never indulged in them at too great length, I owe it more to chance than to **impregnable virtue**.

I would have translated *une vertu incapable de résister à rien* as more like "a (sense of) virtue incapable of resisting anything", which a) seems like an odd/puzzling thing to say, and b) seems like the opposite of a virtue that is "impregnable".

Am I misunderstanding something here?

Edit: I found a Spanish translation that makes more sense to me, which adds an extra possessive:

> Y sin embargo, si he renunciado casi a esas formas demasiado maquinales del placer, o me he negado a seguir adelante, lo debo a mi suerte más que a **mi** virtud incapaz de resistir a cosa alguna.

Comment: To me *Incapable de résister à rien*  can be understood as *capable de résister à tout* (it could have been written *une vertu inexpugnable*),  so I don't object to the use "impregnable". Debatable ? Maybe.

Comment: @None Vraiment? Je vois bien le "double négatif", mais pas du tout convaincu que ce soit équivalent à "capable de résister à tout". En plus, si cela était vrai, ce ne serait peut-être pas logique ici: si la vertu était capable de résister à tout, pourqoui l'auteur ne la créditerait-elle pas, pour mettre en avant plutôt _la chance_? Je pense plutôt que la vertu ne peut effectivement résister à rien, et donc que c'est bel et bien la chance qui a joué en faveur de l'auteur.

Comment: The meaning found in the Spanish translation is the only one that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

En français, le terme *rien* dans ce contexte désigne n'importe quelle chose, et par extension ...tout :

incapable de résister à rien = incapable de résister à quoi que ce soit

= incapable de résister à tout ce qui pourrait arriver

*rien* vient du latin *res*, la chose, comme on le retrouve dans l'expression "un petit rien"

À force d'être utilisé dans des tournures négatives, (je n'ai rien vu = je n'ai pas vu de chose = je n'ai vu aucune chose), il y a eu un glissement de "chose" à "aucune chose" qui est l'usage majoritaire aujourd'hui.